# How to hire a UX professional?

Tags: help

I have no formal development skills, have self-taught myself (with a lot of help from various forums), and have created an okay web application to help contractors.

I've asked generic questions, and have received great advise (thank you!).  But when asking about my specific implementation, I haven't received much.  I get that, and I probably should be paying someone for those services.

That being said, how do I go about creating a relationship with a UX professional and contracting them to help me?  I've come up with a list of question, and am sure there are more.  Maybe there are some good non-biased white-sheets on the topic?

- Is face-to-face communication important?
- How important is cultural similarities?
- Where do I meet them?
- Are there organizations or clubs?
- Are there recommended contracting means (i.e. lump sum, T&M, etc)?
- How is scope best defined?
- What questions should I ask them?
- When should a UX professional be brought on board?
- What qualities from a customer make the UX professional's life better?
- What qualities from a developer make the UX professional's life better?

Comment: This feels like a far too broad a question to be asked on the forum. As a client requesting UX service, it's best to keep an open mind. Describe the perceived problem to them and allow them to suggest possible solutions. e.g. try not to go in with the mindset of I need a mobile app to do XYZ. Often times a UXer will follow up with lots of questions so they can understand the full picture. Bonus points if you can arrange opportunities for the UXer to speak with & test ideas with actual users.

Comment: From the developer, UXer interaction perspective, constant communication is the key. A good UXer shares ideas with the Dev early to get feedback on feasibility and technical concerns. Similarly, if the Dev runs into implementation difficulties, reach out to the UXer to discuss the issue and work together to come up with an alternate approach. If you don't know something, come chat. Don't make guesses.

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad, but it likely isn't on topic.  Think there is a more appropriate place to ask?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address some of your questions, no white papers etc. just 15+ years of doing UX.

**Is face-to-face communication important?**
Absolutely, but that doesn't mean it can't be done remotely. Just as any other communication is infinitely better face to face.

**How important is cultural similarities?**
Absolutely irrelevant IMO unless your application is specific to a particular culture, and even then, at the end of the day they are still just human beings.

**Where do I meet them?**
Wherever the two of you agree upon. This isn't chem warfare, or virus research. We don't need a sterile environment. A coffee shop works great.

**Are there organizations or clubs?**
Just as there are for any profession.

**Are there recommended contracting means (i.e. lump sum, T&M, etc)?**
Not per say. Some people like to bill by the hour, I personally never do this. Strictly per project. It's really up to the two of you to work out what's best for both of you. I typically do 1/4 up front and then 1/4 in the next 3 logical milestones.

**How is scope best defined?**
You have to know what your goal is. What is it you want users to accomplish. You work back from there. Any good UX person can work within your budget to help define the scope.

**What questions should I ask them?**
Ask them how they solve 'problem x' or ask about one of their more difficult problems. UX people are first and foremost problem solvers.

**When should a UX professional be brought on board?**
As soon as possible. The sooner the better. It helps prevent wasted work. Wouldn't you rather know nobody wants to use it this way.. or that way BEFORE you've built it? That said, it's also NEVER too late. But sooner is always better.

**What qualities from a customer make the UX professional's life better?**
That's not the customers job. Honestly, I would be leary of any UX person that was looking for the 'perfect' customer. MY JOB is to make their life better, not the other way around.

**What qualities from a developer make the UX professional's life better?**
Someone that wants to work with me to make the customers life better. Sometimes that means butting heads, but if the end goal is a better customer/ user experience then all the better. The fact that you are asking is a BIG step in the right direction.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks pixelneer.  Yea, I knew the answer that getting a UX guy or gal on board ASAP is key as I have definitely wasted time and money not doing so.  The reason I asked about how the customer could help the UX person is that if I am the customer, I want my UX partner to be happy and efficient and want to work for me, and in turn return some of that benefit to me.  Thanks for your advise.  Michael